# Создание TUI на Python

Tags: python, ui

Всех приветствую. Имеется 4 самостоятельных модуля на питоне, первые два выводят ликвидации, вторые два рыночные сделки с крипто биржи. Все 4 модуля работают по вебсокету.

Задача, реализовать их одновременную работу(С этим проблем нет) с одновременным выводом в приделах одного терминала, каждый модуль должен выводить свои данные в своей блок(Визуально).

Я пересмотрел множество либ для создания tui от curses до pytermui но везде одна проблема, виджеты, панели, окна, круто рисуются и выводят статический текст или список из заранее готовых переменных или словарей, но вебсокет льет данные постоянно. И мне не удалось(Возможно руки кривые =D ) заставить в рисуемые мной оконные модели засунуть вывод из вебсокета. А задача стоит, заставить это все работать именно из под терминала, без GUI.

Возможно я что-то еще не попробовал, а возможно, можно самим питоном как то в приделах одного терминала выводить данные в разные блоки? Любым наставлениям, ссылкам, "пинкам" буду рад!

Comment: Может переложить ответственность на tmux? Создайте в нем четыре панели. Запустите в них четыре приложения.

Comment: Раньше так и делал, но сейчас этот вариант уже не подходит к сожалению... Я даже постарался разобраться в исходниках bpytop, там отрисовка UI идет своими силами, без сторонних либ, но я что-то как то не вник, как это там происходит ))

Comment: Если не надо ничего продвинутого, то https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html. Есть абстракция окна, можно выводить и вводить текст в окнах.

Comment: Curses я пробовал же, я не смог понять как в pad или в window засунуть поток данных

Comment: отдельной нитью добавлять строки в окно

Comment: Я был бы крайне признателен за пояснительный кусок кода, думаю вебсокет можно заменить просто циклом, скажем от 1 до 100(Что бы не реализовывать его), на этом примере я бы уже сориентировался бы. Простоя  не совсем понимаю выражение "отдельной нитью добавлять строки"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Два окна, два потока сообщений:

```
import curses
import threading
import time


def make_log(lock, window, message, interval):

    def run():
        i = 0
        while True:
            lock.acquire()
            window.addstr(f'{i}: {message}\n')
            window.scrollok(1)
            window.refresh()
            lock.release()
            time.sleep(interval)
            i += 1

    return threading.Thread(target=run)


def main(stdscr):
    stdscr.clear()

    lock = threading.Lock()

    half_cols = curses.COLS // 2
    left_thread = make_log(
        lock,
        curses.newwin(curses.LINES, half_cols, 0, 0),
        'left message',
        0.1
    )
    right_thread = make_log(
        lock,
        curses.newwin(curses.LINES, curses.COLS - half_cols, 0, half_cols),
        'right message',
        0.2
    )

    left_thread.start()
    right_thread.start()

    left_thread.join()
    right_thread.join()


curses.wrapper(main)
```

Comment: Благодарю! Все таки я прав был ))) руки у меня кривоваты были )))

Comment: UPDATE: добавил блокировку при перерисовке.